# Is there a way to pass an echo argument with start-process in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automatically connect an Anydesk Session in Powershell.

According to their [CLI documentation](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/command-line-interface-for-windows#connection-commands), you can pass password with echo.

Right now, I'm starting the process like this, since I need the process ID afterward.

```
$app = Start-Process $config.anydesk_path -ArgumentList @($config.ip_addresses[$i], "--plain") -passthr
```

I've tried appending the password to the Argument List like this

```
$app = Start-Process $config.anydesk_path -ArgumentList @($config.connect_pw, $config.ip_addresses[$i], "--plain", "--with-password") -passthru
```

but that doesn't seem to enter the password.

Is there a way to send the password with Start-Process?

Thanks.

Comment: There's almost never a reason to use start-process.  You can use the call operator & with variables.

Comment: @js2010 Call operator does not return a process ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) can only accept input from a file (See `-RedirectStandardInput` parameter).

You can use .NET Framework [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) class directly:

```
$AnyDesk = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process

$AnyDesk.StartInfo.FileName = $config.anydesk_path
$AnyDesk.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

# This allows writing to a standard input stream:
$AnyDesk.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true

$AnyDesk.StartInfo.Arguments = "$($config.ip_addresses[$i]) --plain --with-password"

$AnyDesk.Start()

# Write a password into standard input stream:
$AnyDesk.StandardInput.WriteLine($config.connect_pw)

# Grab a process ID:
$AnyDesk.Id
```